# Filtering dates by time of day (beginner)

Tags: java, date, time, filter

I need to write a method which returns true if a given date is between the hours of 8am and 5pm, and false otherwise. How would I implement this? Thanks a lot!

```
public static boolean isInWorkingHours(String date){


}
```

Comment: Please search StackOveflow before posting. This topic has already been addressed many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the date parameter with the SimpleDateFormat, then set the resulting Date object as time property of a GregorianCalendar instance. Use calendar's get() method to retrieve the hour of day.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html